# Cmake: wrong OpenCV paths generation

Tags: opencv, visual-studio-2012, cmake

**My environment:**

- Windows 7 64
- CMake 2.8.10.2
- Opencv 2.4.4
- Visual Studio Express 2012

**My problem:**

I have a CMake project using Opencv and built under vs11.
Everything works with the pre-built binaries (from c:/opencv/build in my case).
I wanted to change some of the Opencv settings so I had to build it from source (in c:/opencv/build2).
Everything's [built and installed correctly](http://theroundedengineer.blogspot.fr/2011/07/opencv-23-for-vs-2008-from-source.html) in c:/opencv/built2 but I have this error from my IDE :

> error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\opencv\build2\lib\Debug\Debug\opencv_objdetect244d.lib'

Indeed, there no such file.
It seems my CMakeLists.txt script is corrupting the OpenCV_LIBS variable by adding a Debug\ (or Release) subdirectory on each call:

```
MESSAGE ( STATUS "OpenCV_LIBS = ${OpenCV_LIBS}" )
FIND_PACKAGE ( OpenCV COMPONENTS core highgui imgproc objdetect REQUIRED )
MESSAGE ( STATUS "OpenCV_LIBS = ${OpenCV_LIBS}" )
FIND_PACKAGE ( OpenCV COMPONENTS core highgui imgproc objdetect REQUIRED )
MESSAGE ( STATUS "OpenCV_LIBS = ${OpenCV_LIBS}" )
FIND_PACKAGE ( OpenCV COMPONENTS core highgui imgproc objdetect REQUIRED )
MESSAGE ( STATUS "OpenCV_LIBS = ${OpenCV_LIBS}" )
```

outputs:

> OpenCV_LIBS = debug;C:/opencv/build2/lib/Debug/opencv_contrib244d.lib;(...)
>
> OpenCV_LIBS = debug;C:/opencv/build2/lib/Debug/Debug/opencv_objdetect244d.lib;(...)
>
> OpenCV_LIBS = debug;C:/opencv/build2/lib/Debug/Debug/Debug/opencv_objdetect244d.lib;(...)
>
> OpenCV_LIBS = debug;C:/opencv/build2/lib/Debug/Debug/Debug/Debug/opencv_objdetect244d.lib;(...)
>
> OpenCV_LIBS = debug;C:/opencv/build2/lib/Debug/Debug/Debug/Debug/Debug/opencv_objdetect244d.lib;(...)

Am I doing something wrong with my CMake scripts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it seems the `OpenCVConfig.cmake` corrupts the `OpenCV_LIBS` variable when included several times with the `FIND_PACKAGE()` successive calls.

A quick fix is to add `FORCE` to lines **91-94** in `OpenCVConfig.cmake`:

```
# Provide the libs directories to the caller
set(OpenCV_LIB_DIR_OPT "C:/opencv/build2/lib" CACHE PATH "Path where release OpenCV libraries are located" FORCE)
set(OpenCV_LIB_DIR_DBG "C:/opencv/build2/lib" CACHE PATH "Path where debug OpenCV libraries are located" FORCE)
set(OpenCV_3RDPARTY_LIB_DIR_OPT "C:/opencv/build2/3rdparty/lib" CACHE PATH "Path where release 3rdpaty OpenCV dependencies are located" FORCE)
set(OpenCV_3RDPARTY_LIB_DIR_DBG "C:/opencv/build2/3rdparty/lib" CACHE PATH "Path where debug 3rdpaty OpenCV dependencies are located" FORCE)
```

The file to modify is `C:\opencv\cmake\templates\OpenCVConfig.cmake.in`.

Then rebuild/recompile/reinstall OpenCV and then your own project.